# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_loc' in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum

I am trying to sum a column using Pandas "SUM" function.
Here is my code:

> 

```
total_spend = df2['Spend'].sum()
total_sales = df2.loc['14 Day Total Sales'].sum()
roas1= round(total_sales / total_spend,2)
```

I am getting this error :

> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> KeyError: '14 Day Total Sales'

With my understanding the error occur when I tried to access an attribute or method of an object that is 'None' or 'null'.

still getting the same error with:

```
total_sales = df2['14 Day Total Sales'].sum()
```

Here is how the data look like:

```
df2.loc['14 Day Total Sales']
```

[image]

sometimes there is no sells and the value will be 0, but it is not 'null' or 'none'.
So I don’t understand why I get the error
hope that make sense, spent my weekend finding a solution...
Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `print(df2.columns)` please?

Comment: `Index(['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Portfolio name', 'Currency', 'Campaign Name',
       'Ad Group Name', 'Targeting', 'Match Type', 'Customer Search Term',
       'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Click-Thru Rate (CTR)',
       'Cost Per Click (CPC)', 'Spend', '14 Day Total Sales ',
       'Total Advertising Cost of Sales (ACOS) ',
       'Total Return on Advertising Spend (ROAS)', '14 Day Total Orders (#)',
       '14 Day Total Units (#)', '14 Day Conversion Rate'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: You have a trailing whitespace `'14 Day Total Sales '`. Try `df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()` and your code would work.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
 total_sales = df2.loc(df2['14 Day Total Sales']).sum()
```

work:

```
   total_sales = df2['14 Day Total Sales'].sum()
```